# USB charge controller avaliable for hobbyists?

Tags: usb

I'm interested in creating my own USB charger. For a basic circuit, I obviously can short (through a resistor, for safety reasons) between D+ and D-, creating a DCP, hence letting the device draw 5V/500mA from a circuit built around LM7805 (with safety precautions).

The question is, is it now, as of 2018, more advanced charge controllers are available to the general public?

For example, there are modules available from various Chinese manufacturers, built around uP9616, which supports QC. Using a complete module, obviously takes out all the fun in building, not to mention lack of features I'd like to have (V/I display at output). I've been searching for days, but I cannot find any IC available to the general public. Am I missing something or should we accept 5V/500mA?

Comment: What's a usb charger exactly? Usb input? Usb output?, Charges what?

Comment: In general, the USB quick charge controller and the voltage regulator controller are separate chips. That's even more fun building …

Comment: Hello Jasen. USB charger similar to regular wall charger, devices intended to be charged are regular USB devices (from charging point of view) such as phones, tablets, etc. Input will be some kind of switched power supply (DC).

Comment: Hello CL. Yes they are separate, indeed fun to make.

Comment: I assume this is a fun project because there is no way you can compete in price or quality with a mass produced charger. By the way USB 3 allows a much higher current than 500mA.

Comment: It's fun from electronics point of view (design & build). There's no intent to compete. As for quality, while it's no competition, I intend it to have all necessary parts (apart from PCB maybe).

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic here. But a quick Google search shows that chips like the CHY100 or NCP4371 are available from all large distributors.

Comment: Actually, it is not much fun designing advanced chargers. It is more like a hard engineering work that requires a good bit of experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you short D+ with D- inside your charger port/cable, devices will take up to 1.5 A, not 500 mA.

If you want to build a QC charger, it is quite more complicated. To start, take a look at [Texas Instruments reference guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu917/tidu917.pdf)

[image]

If you want to embark on Power Delivery, it is even more challenging. To start, look into educational materials [like this from STI](http://www.st.com/resource/en/product_presentation/usb_type-c.pdf). An example for a powerbank:

[image]

Have fun and a good luck.

Comment: Hello Ali Chen and thank you! As a side note - by "fun", I meant creating.